# Can I get a list of Active Directory properties/attributes in XML format?

Tags: active-directory

Does Microsoft have a URL in th e internet from which we can get the list of all possible properties/attributes that exist in the different versions of Active Directory?

I woul like to get, for example, the property name, type and length in XML format.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any such reference, but Active Directory MVP Richard Mueller has a great site which provides these kind of reference materials as Excel tables.

See his [Links & References](http://www.rlmueller.net/Links_and_References.htm) page - very helpful indeed!

Marc